# QT5.7 webengine how to set Notification.permission to granted?

Tags: html, c++, qt, qtwebengine

Now ,I found the qt webengine window.Notification.Permission default value is denied, how to set this value to "granted"?

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49312744/auto-grant-access-to-mic-and-camera-with-qt-webengine